# Tower damage + Champion Defense

Tags: league-of-legends

I am trying to work out how turret damage is affected by armour, skills and masteries.

Here is the information for turret damage as far as I am aware:

```
Turret        Range  Base HP    AD     Gains 6 AD every:        AD Caps at:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Outer Tower   1000*  Various    152    1 min at each :40 second mark.   200
Middle Tower  1000*  Various    197    1 min starting at 7:00 mark.     263
Inner Tower   1000*  Various    210    1 min starting at 16:00 mark.    330
Nexus Tower   1000*  Various    115    1 min at each :40 second mark.   343
Nexus Obelisk 1000*    9999*    999    N/A                              N/A
```

- Does armour reduce it, the same it
  would for auto attacks?
- Do items like  thornmail and skills like Rammus' curl reflect damage?
- Do skills like Maoki's ultimate (-15% damage in the aoe) or Alistair's ultimate (-75% damage on self) affect the turret damage?
- Does the last defensive mastery negate 4% of the damage?

Comment: Thornmail and Defensive Ball Curl do *not* reflect the damage back to a tower. However, you want to use Curl with Rammus when attacking a tower, anyway, because it grants him extra armor, which means more damage on the tower via Spiked Shell. I do not know about any of the rest, however.

Comment: I know through playing Alistar that his ult reduces the damage he takes from towers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets break this out piece by piece.

> - Does armour reduce it, the same it would for auto attacks?

Armor does in fact reduce the damage you take from normal towers. The base tower however deals true damage.

> - Do items like thornmail and skills like Rammus' curl reflect damage?

Simple answer: No. Most abilities do not deal damage to towers either. Exceptions include Heimerdinger's turrets and Alistar's passive.

> - Do skills like Maoki's ultimate (-15% damage in the aoe) or Alistair's ultimate (-75% damage on self) affect the turret damage?

Maoki's ultimate does not reduce damage taken from turrets but Alistar's ultimate does.

> - Does the last defensive mastery negate 4% of the damage?

I believe so for the following reasons. It says it reduces "All damage" doesnt exclude towers specifically (the way Maoki's ultimate description does).

Hope that helps.

Comment: All skills that behave differently towards towers have it explicitly stated in their tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about all. But what I'm positive about is that Maokai's ultimate DOES NOT reduce tower damage. And that's because it is stated in the skill description.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret also states that :

> Turret damage is mitigated by your armor, unless they are Shrine (spawn) turrets which ignore all resistances and immunities. Turret armor is not affected by your armor penetration/reduction.

The best way to know about thornmail/curl would be a test I guess. (But curl already do some damage, so you need to substract from what you see)